# Getting around not being able to nest aggregators, sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm grouping the tuples in a relation on InstructorNo and CourseNo, where a teacher is in a tuple with a course if they can teach it. I want to select instructors that can teach the same number of courses as the instructor in the list that can teach the most courses.

For example, if Mr.Smith can teach the most courses out of all the teachers in the relation I want to select Mr.Smith and anybody else that can teach the same number of courses he can.

What I'd really like to do is something like this:

`select InstructorNo, COUNT(InstCourses.CourseNo) as NoTeachableCourses
from
...
group by InstructorNo
having COUNT(InstCourses.CourseNo) = MAX(COUNT(InstCourses.CourseNo))`

But that's illegal because of the nested aggregations `MAX(COUNT...`. How can I get this functionality without being able to nest aggregators? I'm not sure how many teachers I'll need to select in a given query, so I'm not sure if `TOP` or `TOP WITH TIES` will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `TOP` or `TOP WITH TIES`:

```
select top(1) with ties InstructorNo, COUNT(InstCourses.CourseNo) as NoTeachableCourses
from
...
group by InstructorNo
order by NoTeachableCourses desc;
```

Comment: seems like I need to specify an integer after `TOP` or `TOP WITH TIES`. Is there a way around that? I'm not sure how many teachers I'll need to select in any single query

Comment: to be clear, I need to select all the instructors that can teach the same number of courses that the top instructor can

Comment: @Adam, it seems that `TOP WITH TIES 1` is what you need here. `1` is correct number when used `WITH TIES` in this query.